# What is a safe way of making a Future available between HTTP requests?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a long-running operation in a Spring Boot web application.
This is how it works:

- When the user clicks a button, a `POST` request is made and the operation starts.
- Because the operation will take a long time, it is started asynchronously and a response is sent immediately.
- Using JavaScript, I periodically send `GET` requests to find out if the operation has finished.

Here are the request handlers:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

@RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
String start(HttpSession session) {
    Future<String> result = resultService.result();
    session.setAttribute("result", result);
    return "started";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/status")
@ResponseBody
String status(HttpSession session) throws Exception {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Future<String> result = (Future<String>) session.getAttribute("result");
    if (result != null && result.isDone()) {
        return result.get();
    } else {
        return "working";
    }
}
```

And this is the long-running operation (in a separate bean):

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;

@Async
@Override
public Future<String> result() {
    String result = computeResult(); // takes long
    return new AsyncResult<String>(result);
}
```

The complete example is [on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/cosminul/serial-future).
Also, here's [a GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGnUE.gif) showing how it works.

Now, this works, but the problem is that SonarQube raised an issue:

> Make "Future" and its parameters serializable or don't store it in the session.

It explained that

> the session [...] may be written to disk anyway, as the server manages its memory use in a process called "passivation". Further, some servers automatically write their active sessions out to file at shutdown & deserialize any such sessions at startup.
>
> See [MITRE, CWE-579](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/579.html) - J2EE Bad Practices: Non-serializable Object Stored in Session

Since I can't make `Future` serializable, what would be a better way to keep track of the long-running operation between requests?

Comment: Do you want this operation to be "deserialized", or rather resumed, on startup? If so then you have to conceive of some way to save the state of the operation and store that on the session, perhaps having that state class implement Future. If not, then I would simply store a new class on the session, one which contains a transient Future field. I am not familiar with SpringMVC so I wouldn't be surprised if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: My solution, that I can not access right now, used DeferredResult and ListenableFuture.. you might be able to find the tutorial I used using those keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, this works, but the problem is that SonarQube raised an issue:

To fix the above issue, you can write a wrapper class implementing `Serializable` that contains the result of the `Future` object along with the `Future` object as transient. And you can place this `wrapper` object in the session instead of directly putting the `Future` object.

Ex:

```
public class ResultWrapper implements Serializable {
    private String result = "working"; //String, since the resultService.result() is returning Future<String>
    private transient Future future; //transient as it is not serializable.

    public String getResult() {
        if (future != null && future.isDone()) {
            result = future.get();
            //Once the future is done, call the session.setAttribute(...) so that value of result field is replicated across the JVM nodes.
        }
        return result;
     }
}
```

Note that this just solves the issue you have raised regarding the SonarQube. But it doesn't really provide `failover` or `handles activation/passivation` even if the session replication is active.

If there are two nodes M1 & M2 on which the webapp is running with session replication in place, the async job `computeResult();` will obviously be running only on one of the machines (the one which received the initial request) and if that machine goes down all the requests will be forwarded to the other active machine and the result will always return "working" forever.

Another issue which applies even the webapp is running on a single node is that, if the session gets passivated the `future` will not be passivated as it is transient and so you will loose reference to that object and reactivated wrapper will have future obj as null. Finally the result is same as above case.